# angular2 how to open ng-zorro message box while the page is loading

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I added **[ngzorro](https://ng.ant.design/components/notification/en)** message box to my project, i want to know how to open that message box while the page is loading without using click event

**[stack-blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmj5sd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

code here

**commonlayout.html**

```
<router-outlet (load)="createBasicNotification()">
      
</router-outlet>
```

.ts

```
 createBasicNotification(): void {
    this.notification.blank(
      'Notification Title',
      'I will never close automatically. I will be close automatically. I will never close automatically.',
      { nzDuration: 0 }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue
i added `ngOnInit`   to

```
`ngOnInit() {  `this.createBasicNotification() ; true;`}`
```